# Little guide of Simple Data binding in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

```
    DataSet DataSet1 = new DataSet(); 
    DataTable t = DataSet1.Tables.Add("employee"); 
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",t,"salary");
```

i wanted to know that what does **Text** here means in this Add function?

Comment: You should check [`Add` method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6y3aby2.aspx), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the `Text` property of `TextBox(textbox1)` is going to be binded

Comment: the text property of the textbox or the name of the textbox?

Comment: Text property of the textbox. Text property contains the text which is actually shown by TextBox

Answer (score 3):

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",t,"salary");
```

This means:

1. To the `textbox1` control...
2. The `.Text` property of this textbox element.
3. Use the dataset `t`.
4. Find the value of the salary field and use that.

Answer (score 1):

The name of `textBox1` property which should recieve the value from DB.

So `textBox1.Text` property after successful loading will contain the data from `salary` field of `t` DataTable object.

Comment: the name of textbox or the text property of the textbox ? :S

Comment: The `Text` property of textbox